# User entered String splitting

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

i am new at Progress openedge! I would like to know how to split a user entered String with **using procedure**!
length of string could be max 2000 and every single Line contains max 35 Character.And spaces between Words must be also to considered.if a single line max > 35 then must begin with another line but not like this : ....hel
                                                                   lo.........

it has to after 35.Line cutting off and spring next line but the spaces make me so confused and i cant find any Algorithm
For example:

```
myfield2 =  "Many districts and landmarks in New York City are well known, and the city received a record 62.8 million tourists in 2017".

if index(myfield2,spacee) = 0 then do:

          do while ii < length(myfield2) :
           line = substring(myfield2,ii,35).
           ii = ii + 35.            
         end.
       end.
     display line.    
   else if index(myfield2,spacee) <> 0 and length(myfield2) < 35  then do: 

.......
```

sth like this ?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the space character left to your 35th character using R-INDEX

`R-INDEX (myfield2, " ", ii) .`

Comment: could you gimme an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
define variable t as character no-undo.
define variable x as character no-undo format "x(36)".

define variable i as integer   no-undo.
define variable n as integer   no-undo.

t = "Many districts and landmarks in New York City are well known, and the city received a record 62.8 million tourists in 2017".
n = num-entries( t, " " ).

do i = 1 to n:

  if length( x + entry( i, t, " " )) < 35 then
    do:
      x = x + entry( i, t, " " ) + " ".
      next.
    end.

  display x with frame a down.
  down 1 with frame a.

  x = entry( i, t, " " ) + " ".

end.

display x with frame a down.
```

or, if you prefer a variable with embedded newlines:

```
define variable t as character no-undo.
define variable x as character no-undo format "x(36)".

define variable i as integer   no-undo.
define variable j as integer   no-undo.
define variable n as integer   no-undo.

t = "Many districts and landmarks in New York City are well known, and the city received a record 62.8 million tourists in 2017".
n = num-entries( t, " " ).

do i = 1 to n:

  if j < 35 and
    (j + length( entry( i, t, " " )) + 1) < 35 then
    do:
      x = x + entry( i, t, " " ) + " ".
      j = j + length( entry( i, t, " " )) + 1.
      next.
    end.

  j = length( entry( i, t, " " )) + 1.
  x = x + "~n" + entry( i, t, " " ) + " ".

end.

display x view-as editor size 40 by 10.
```

Comment: hey tom , first of all thanks your help! it must be a pdf a looks like this -->https://ibb.co/hCSEES   
Text part increases by the text size..( more words and area must be bigger) i thought   textlenght / 35 ! and after 35.word it must be cut off if there is no space! i already wrote area-line drawing procedure but im not stuck on text-area :( i mean it has to be optimal : )

Comment: The code in my answer splits the text at the last space prior to going over 35 characters and then starts a new line and does it again as many times as necessary.  To me that sounds like what you are asking for in both your question and in the comment above but I'm sorry if I do not understand what you are asking for.

Comment: what if there is no "spaces/blanks".It must cut it off 35.line exactly but for it i have to use substring or entry ? could you please edit it for also if there are no blanks ?

Comment: besides it wont gimme the whole text if the next line contains small text. for Exmp:    run ABC("Many districts and landmarks in New York City are well known, and the city received a record 62.8 million tourists in 2017").
it returns elements till "tourists" and next line doesnt begin with "tourists in 2017". thanks.

Comment: a line contains 35 Char.Your code doesnt cut it off from 35. for example : "Many districts and landmarks in Stockholm are well known, 
and the city received a record 62.8 million tourists in 2017".1.line is : Many districts and landmarks in Stockholm and it contains more than 35 Char.it means "stockholm" has to begin with next row otherwise text overflows from Field.And if there is no blank then cut it off directly from 36.and if next line has also no blank then cut it off from 72.line if 3.row contains blank(" ") then blanks must be considered. it must be like this ! i hope i was clear.Thx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cInput  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO INITIAL 
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et ~
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet ~
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ~
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, ~
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea ~
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.".

DEFINE VARIABLE cOutput AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iPos    AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iPrev   AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO INITIAL 1 . 
DEFINE VARIABLE iLength AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN iLength = LENGTH (cInput, "CHARACTER").

repeatLoop:
REPEAT:
    iPos = R-INDEX (cInput, " ", iPrev + 35) . 

    IF iPos = 0 THEN 
        ASSIGN iPos = iLength .  

    ASSIGN cOutput = cOutput + TRIM (SUBSTRING (cInput, iPrev, iPos - iPrev, "CHARACTER")) + "|~n".

    IF iPos + 35 >= iLength THEN DO: 
        ASSIGN cOutput = cOutput + TRIM (SUBSTRING (cInput, iPos, -1, "CHARACTER")) .

        LEAVE repeatLoop. 
    END.

    ASSIGN iPrev = iPos . 
END.

MESSAGE cOutput
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
```

Comment: it wont cut it off the text like this : modtemLoremipsumdolorsitametconsetetursadipscingelitrseddiamnonumyeirporinviduntutlaboreet.Commentsusedtoasforclarificationoro. i mean the text without spaces.

Comment: if text is throughout, without blanks then it has to be cutted from directly 36.line as well but it could be like this : abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdea --> 36.line must begin with next line and if there are blanks after 36.line then your code must be executed.if they are no blanks then must  be cutted again after 36.line but this time to be considered blanks if exists.. it must go like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Should be work for you. It breaks the text into a temp table. You can break text to any text length you desire, just by adjusting the second parameter from procedure call.

```
def temp-table tt-editor no-undo
    field linha      as integer
    field conteudo   as character format 'x(80)':U
    index editor-id is primary unique 
          linha.

procedure pi-print-editor:
    def input param c-editor    as char    no-undo.
    def input param i-len       as integer no-undo.

    def var i-linha  as integer no-undo.
    def var i-aux    as integer no-undo.
    def var c-aux    as char    no-undo.
    def var c-ret    as char    no-undo.

    IF c-editor = ? or i-len = ? THEN
        RETURN.

    for each tt-editor:
        delete tt-editor.
    end.

    assign c-ret = chr(255) + chr(255).

    do  while c-editor <> "":
        if  c-editor <> "" then do:
            assign i-aux = index(c-editor, chr(10)).

            IF i-aux = 0 THEN DO:
                assign i-aux = index(c-editor, chr(13)).
            END.
            if  i-aux > i-len or (i-aux = 0 and length(c-editor) > i-len) then
                assign i-aux = r-index(c-editor, " ", i-len + 1).
            if  i-aux = 0 then
                assign c-aux = substr(c-editor, 1, i-len)
                       c-editor = substr(c-editor, i-len + 1).
            else
                assign c-aux = substr(c-editor, 1, i-aux - 1)
                       c-editor = substr(c-editor, i-aux + 1).
            if  i-len = 0 then
                assign entry(1, c-ret, chr(255)) = c-aux.
            else do:
                assign i-linha = i-linha + 1.
                create tt-editor.
                assign tt-editor.linha    = i-linha
                       tt-editor.conteudo = c-aux.
            end.
        end.
        if  i-len = 0 then
            return c-ret.
    end.
    return c-ret.
end procedure.

RUN pi-print-editor ('modtemLoremipsumdolorsitametconsetetursadipscingelitrseddiamnonumyeirporinviduntutlaboreet.Commentsusedtoasforclarificationoro. i mean the text without spaces.',35).

FOR EACH tt-editor:
    DISP tt-editor.conteudo FORMAT 'x(40)' LENGTH(conteudo) WITH WIDTH 333.
END.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks bruno : ) but im a beginner and this temp-table or other stuff are a bit complicated for me! i jsut need something more easier : ) i actually wrote some code but it wont cut text off after 35.line if there is no blank! dont know how to show you my code : ) it can not fit in comment area :)